# How do I open/map a network drive share in Ubuntu (Nautilus)?

Tags: linux, networking, ftp, network-shares, smb

I just moved from Windows to Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS and I'm still adapting, I'm using it on my work laptop and I need to reach network shared folders.

In Windows I would just open the file explorer and type \ServerName\Folder in to the address bar or right click on Computer, Map network drive... but here I can't find this option anywhere.

In Nautilus, I tried with smb://servername/Share but I get the error message "Unable to access location".

PS
Ubuntu is not in corporate domain but I use a VPN

Comment: Are you using the full DNS name of the server, or the shortened (single-component) name? Can you `ping` the server? Could you try running `smbclient -U username //servername/share` from the terminal? Was your Windows machine previously part of the corporate domain (or do you know if non-domain Windows machines could access the server)?

Comment: I can ping the serverś IP address but not the DNS, I tried to run the command you sent me but then it ask "Enter WORKGROUP\username's password:" when I need to log in with DOMAIN\username's password.